# New identity for lcm of the first n integers and the second Chebyshev function

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have found a function to create the lowest common multiples for the first $n$ positive integers:
$$\text{lcm}(n):=\prod_{m=2}^{n}C_m(1),$$
where $C_m(1)$ is the [cyclotomic polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html) of order $m$ and $n\geq2.$

The *Mathematica* functions:

```
lcm[n_] := Product[Cyclotomic[m, 1], {m, 2, n}]
\[Psi][x_] := Sum[Log[Cyclotomic[n, 1]], {n, 2, x}]
Table[Product[Cyclotomic[n, 1], {n, 2, m}], {m, 0, 28}],
```

the last of which produces this sequence at [OEIS A003418](http://oeis.org/A003418)

Is this a known function?

Comment: This appears related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1

Comment: @joro, thanks. Somehow, I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\log C_m(1) = \Lambda(m)$ for $m \ge 2$, where $\Lambda$ is the Von Mangoldt function, this seems to be a restatement of the identity

$$\mathrm{lcm} \{1,\ldots,n\} = \exp \psi(n) = \exp\bigl( \sum_{m=1}^n \Lambda(m) \bigr) = \exp\bigl( \sum_{m=2}^n \log C_m(1) \bigr).$$

Comment: Thanks. The RHS is my middle _Mathematica_ statement. So, it seems I have re-invented the wheel and called it "Fire."

Comment: If you are able to burn things with it, or even heat them up, let us know.